# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list', Remove duplicate items in a list

Tags: python

When I type the following code. I just try to remove the duplicate items in an list. There may be 10K pairs in this list.

```
>>> t = [['a','1'],['a','1'],['a','2']...]
>>> t = list(set(t))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
t = list(set(t))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
```

Comment: By the way, I am using Python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace lists with tuples: `('a','1')`. As far as I know tuples are hashable.

Comment: @xlk3099 try in future investigate problems first, docs for `set` explicitly mention that elements have to be hashable, and it is not hard to find is list hashable.

Comment: @Andrey -- tuples are hashable so long as all of the elements are hashable.  `hash(([],))` fails for example

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it still comes up first in Google.  Tuples work if you only have two elements each "sub-list", but if you want to remove duplicate sub-lists more generally if you have a list like:

```
a=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,4],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2]]
```

you can use

```
b=[a[x] for x in range(len(a)) if not(a[x] in a[:x])]
```

and b will have only the unique elements from a